# Printing multiple values from a dictionary after reading it from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, parsing, pom.xml

I am having trouble coming up with a solution to a program I am writing.
I am reading decencies from a pom file after reading them I save them into a dictionary.
After saving them into a dictionary I want to output in a specific way. As follows:

My code on how I am parsing the pom file:

```
for dep in depend:
    infoList = []
    counter += 1
    for child in dep.getchildren():
        infoList.append(child.tag.split('}')[1])
        infoList.append(child.text)

    #list where data is being stored
    dependencyInfo[infoList[1]].update({infoList[2] : infoList[3],infoList[4] : infoList[5]})
                   
#print statement of all the data
print("""%i Dependency where found in %s's pom file.""" % (counter,projectName))
print(dependencyInfo)
```

The output is

```
11 Dependency where found in my-application1's pom file.
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'junit': {'artifactId': 'junit', 'version': '3.8.1'}, 'org.hibernate': {'artifactId': 'ejb3-persistence', 'version': '1.0.1.GA'}, 'javax.sql': {'artifactId': 'jdbc-stdext', 'version': '2.0'}, '
javax.transaction': {'artifactId': 'jta', 'version': '1.0.1B'}, 'mysql': {'artifactId': 'mysql-connector-java', 'version': '5.1.14'}, 'slf4j-api': {'groupId': 'org.slf4j', 'type': 'jar'}, 'org.slf4j': {'artifactId': 'slf4j
-simple', 'version': '1.6.1'}})
```

Now I want to rearrange the data as follows

```
groupId = junit
artifactId = junit
version = 3.8.1
.
.
groupId = javax.transaction 
artifactId = jta
version = 1.0.1B
```

Comment: `dict.items()` may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
for groupId, artifact in dependencyInfo.items():
    artifactId = artifact["artifactId"]
    version = artifact["version"]

    print(f"groupId = {groupId}")
    print(f"artifactId = {artifactId}")
    print(f"version = {version}")
    print()
```

Note that your `dependencyInfo` has a slight error, this entry: `'slf4j-api': {'groupId': 'org.slf4j', 'type': 'jar'}` needs to have the `artifactId` in the body instead and `groupId` as the key.

To accommodate for where `groupId` and `artifactId` could be switched, in addition to other fields like `type`, you could use this:

```
for dependencyId, info in dependencyInfo.items():
    additionalInfo = {}

    groupId = None
    artifactId = None

    for infoName, infoValue in info.items():
        if infoName == "artifactId":
            artifactId = info["artifactId"]
            groupId = dependencyId
        elif infoName == "groupId":
            artifactId = dependencyId
            groupId = info["groupId"]
        else:
            additionalInfo[infoName] = infoValue

    if groupId:
        print(f"groupId = {groupId}")

    if artifactId:
        print(f"artifactId = {artifactId}")

    for infoName, infoValue in additionalInfo.items():
        print(f"{infoName} = {infoValue}")

    print()
```

Resulting output for your `dependencyInfo`:

```
groupId = junit
artifactId = junit
version = 3.8.1

groupId = org.hibernate
artifactId = ejb3-persistence
version = 1.0.1.GA

groupId = javax.sql
artifactId = jdbc-stdext
version = 2.0

groupId = javax.transaction
artifactId = jta
version = 1.0.1B

groupId = mysql
artifactId = mysql-connector-java
version = 5.1.14

groupId = org.slf4j
artifactId = slf4j-api
type = jar

groupId = org.slf4j
artifactId = slf4j-simple
version = 1.6.1
```

Though this will do unexpected things if neither `groupId` or `artifactId` is present, or both are present at the same time in the body.

Comment: Your solution worked! Thank you. Upon running it it threw back and error because of what you said in your note. That certain dependency has a <type> tag. Would you know what condition I would use to avoid this issue?

Comment: @BigO Depends on what you want, do you want me to skip over  entries that have that type of error, or do you want me to parse them correctly instead of having error be thrown?

Comment: Parse them correctly please, because in some other pom files that I just opened it has a scope tag and exclusions tag as well.

Comment: Yes it works, but for some reason it skips some outputs. Like it doesnt output all 11 dependencies, only 7. I''ll try to figure it out. Thank you very much.